# Update css using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update the css of my navbar using jQuery.

Where you would normally define the css as:

```
.navbar-static-top .navbar-nav > .active > a{
  background-color: black;
}
```

What do I use for the class selector (without typing each element individually)?

```
$(".navbar-static-top .navbar-nav > .active > a").css({"background-color": "black"});
```

Comment: What you have should (and does) work absolutely fine. If it's not working for you, check the console for errors. However it should be noted that using `css()` should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: this depends on how you do the markup in html, ideally i would always give a class name to the DOM object `a` / `span` / `div` etc if they are way to much nested as in this case!

Comment: #Robert, Edit your question and provide full html code, Because i am confused with CSS classesd

Comment: @Rory McCrossan what would you use instead of .css()? I am not receiving any console errors.

Comment: Does it work with the stylesheet ? Is your background-color applied ? Instead of .css() use .addClass() and define your bakcouground-color class.

Comment: @Robert I'd use `addClass()` and make sure the CSS rule is specific enough to override any existing stylig on the element.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I think my issue is that the active class is also applied via jQuery based on the link people use to arrive to the page. One could be running quicker than the other. I am going to try and apply the correct styling from the outset when the active class is originally applied.

Comment: @Robert Your code is working https://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/576/

Answer (score 1):

try out using find

```
jQuery(".navbar-static-top .navbar-nav").find(".active").find("a").css("background-color","#000");
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use below js to apply css.

```
jQuery(".navbar-static-top .navbar-nav").find(".active").children("a").css("background-color","#000000");
```

I hope this code is useful for you.